# How to add title to ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i can't set title to Action bar sherlock. Here is my code:

```
public void addNavaigationBar(){

       //Create Action Bar sherlock
ActionBar navigation_bar =  getSupportActionBar();



//Setting standart navigation bar view
navigation_bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);



navigation_bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
navigation_bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
navigation_bar.setTitle("Testing");



}
```

I want to add Testing tile but it don't changes. This should be easy but i can't find it.

Also i am wondering if i could create this navigation bar on top and Tab bar on bottom with Action bar sherlock ?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Sorry this is working, it's my other mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I can't find the documentation, but it's not considered best practices to place Android tabs on the bottom - something about that being how it's done on iOS. Theoretically, though, it could be possible with SplitWhenNarrow if you filled the top bar with enough other things - but it would be unreliable, because on a tablet, for example, there might be enough space to load the tabs with everything else on the top bar.

Edit~ Just tested in my code - you can leave out the show title method(true) and still call setTitle on the actionbar, and it sets the title properly.

Comment: No, Android tabs should be put at the top: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: @goncalossilva That's why I said: "First off, I can't find the documentation, but it's not considered best practices to place Android tabs on the bottom..." right at the top of my post? I don't understand this downvote. I provided a more detailed explanation as well as speculation, only after the modifier 'theoretically'.

Comment: Yes, as long as you make some kind of edit in your answer (SO blocked my vote).

Comment: Done, sorry for the confusion. Your advise was solid.

Answer (score 11):

Add this into your `onCreate`

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("<Your Title Here>")
```

example:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

          //Actionbar Stuff
          getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hope This Helped!")

    }
//REST OF CLASS HERE
}
```